# Windows 8 Image Slider

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is the image slider that the Windows 8 Camera app uses available as a control within the framework? It has nice transitions between images and provides previous and next buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a FlipView control if you are referring to that.

Answer (score 1):

There is callisto refernce in nuget there you can find flipview like windows 8 app store

Answer (score 0):

You have some similar controls already built-in, such as FlipView if you want the previous and next buttons.

But if you want all the features in the image gallery application (with zooming capabilities), you will have to create your own component. I did, and it was quite painful, but sadly I did not have the time to package it properly to share with the community. Maybe someone else did it.